# How to set the JDK version to compile JSP pages?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, google-app-engine, unsupported-class-version

I made a GAE project in Eclipse Luna. All worked fine until I added a JSP page.
Now, as I deploy new versions, no matters if the JSP is called or not, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/jsp/web/jsp/RecordExtraCost_jsp : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

The cause of this, reading the Internet, is due to a code compiled with Java 8 which at runtime is running on Java 7.
I checked all the settings and everything looks fine. In fact, as I remove the JSP file and I redeploy, everything works again.

So the only hypothesis is that eclipse is using the JDK 8 to compile JSP. Is that possible? How do I fix this without removing the JDK 8 from my machine?

Comment: Have you tried adding 1.7 to your machine and fiddling with the build path to get Eclipse to use that instead?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes the 1.7 is installed and it's being used until I add a jsp file. In the build path only the 1.7 is set.

Comment: ...Ohhh. I'm stupid. I'm stumped then.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes me too, I tried everything. I found as a solution to physically remove the 1.8 from the system. But Dave, I'm afraid: I cannot do it.

Answer (score 0):

1) Install the JDK 1.7 on your PC.

2) On your eclipse Settings go to Java> Installed JREs.

3) Remove the 1.8 JDK/JRE and add the 1.7 version.

4)  clean and build.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I already have the 1.7 installed, in fact, it works if I remove the .jsp. If with "remove the 1.8" you mean uncheck it, I already did this. If you mean remove, sorry, I cannot accept it as a solution because I need the 1.8 for other projects.